# Django: record.save() throws error or hangs

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm using MySQL as my django's database backend. Very often (every 5 minutes) I need to update a field or two in the table. I'm using the `save(update_fields=['myfield'])` method to do so. But occasionally, I'm getting `Save with update_fields did not affect any rows` error. Also, sometimes the entire program hangs on the `save()` method. I have to type ctrl-c twice to exit it.

I use the `objects.get()` to retrieve the record, which needs to be updated. If I remove `update_fields` and just use `save()`, I sometimes get `(1062, "Duplicate entry 'field_value' for key 'PRIMARY'")` error on my primary key.

Anybody understands the behavior? Thanks.

EDIT:

The program looks like below (omitted irrelevant codes):

```
for new_data in db.change():
    record = User.objects.get(DeviceID=deviceid)
    record.curr_status=new_data
    record.save()
```

Comment: You need to show more code. Single statements you listed is not enough to explain.

Comment: @ShangWang Thanks. Just added them.